# MS SQL Server order depends on fields in select statement

Tags: sql-server

We have an old system which splits up long strings of text and stores them in a table like so:

```
The compu
ter is no
t working
```

along with some other data for each row.

I'm selecting some data from the table like so:

```
select a.Field1, a.Field2, a.Field3
from TableA a
```

Resulting nicely in:

```
Field1      Field2      Field3
The compu       2          3
ter is no       2          3
t working       2          3
```

However, if I add a specific column, `Field4` to the select statement the order gets screwed up:

```
select a.Field1, a.Field2, a.Field3, a.Field4
from TableA a

Field1      Field2      Field3      Field4
ter is no       2          3          1
The compu       2          3          1
t working       2          3          1
```

If I use a star in the select statement it works fine:

```
select *
from TableA a

Field1      Field2      Field3      Field4     Field5
ter is no       2          3          1           5
The compu       2          3          1           5
t working       2          3          1           5
```

So, I cannot really use any `order by` statement since there is nothing to order by.

Can anybody come up with any suggestions to why I get the right order without `Field4` in the query and the wrong order with it?

Comment: This is probably the best article I have encountered on the topic of hoping for an order without an order by. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/conor_cunningham_msft/archive/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you dont use `ORDER BY` clause there is no guarantee in what order the rows will be returned and depending on SQL Server for ordering rows for you is a recipe of disaster.

Without using Order By clause one thing that may influence the order in which rows are returned is your  indexes defined on your table.

But again there is no guarantee and if Order matters, you should always use Order by clause with your select statements.

Answer (score 1):

Try performing a function on it:

```
select a.Field1, a.Field2, a.Field3, isnull(a.Field4,'') AS [Field4]
from TableA a
```

Then shoot your DB architect.

Comment: it made no difference but I like the idea about the shooting

Answer (score 0):

You perhaps could use a subquery.

```
select result.field1
        , result.field2
        , result.field3
        , a.field4
    from (
            select a.id
                    , a.field1
                    , a.field2
                    , a.field3
                from TableA a
        ) result
        join TableA a
            on  a.id = result.id
```

Or else, make sure you have an `Id` column by which the result may get ordered.

```
TableA
-----------------------------------------------
 Id  |  field1 |  field2  |  field3  |  field4
-----------------------------------------------
```

Or even a sort order column which will serve your purpose.

```
TableA
-------------------------------------------------------
 field1  |  field2  |  field3  |  field4  |  sortOrder
-------------------------------------------------------
 This st |    ''    |    ''    |    ''    |    1
-------------------------------------------------------
 really  |    ''    |    ''    |    ''    |    3
-------------------------------------------------------
 g       |    ''    |    ''    |    ''    |    5
-------------------------------------------------------
 ring is |    ''    |    ''    |    ''    |    2
-------------------------------------------------------
 too lon |    ''    |    ''    |    ''    |    4
```

Which you can order as previously stated.

```
select a.field1
        , a.field2
        , a.field3
        , a.field4
    from TableA a
    order by sortOrder asc
```

Output:

```
 field1  |  field2  |  field3  |  field4  
-----------------------------------------
 This st |    ''    |    ''    |    ''    
-----------------------------------------
 ring is |    ''    |    ''    |    ''   
-----------------------------------------
 really  |    ''    |    ''    |    ''   
-----------------------------------------
 too lon |    ''    |    ''    |    ''   
-----------------------------------------
 g       |    ''    |    ''    |    ''
```